# create a global NSMutableArray

Tags: nsmutablearray, global

I have a lot of View Controller and all use the same Class (ViewController).

In ViewController.m I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    pedidoNomeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    pedidoValorArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

and when I go to View Controller number 2 my array pedidoNomeArray and pedidoValorArray are null.

What I have to do to use the same array in all my View Controllers?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason could be that you are not using ARC. In this case you assign the newly initialized array directly to an ivar, i.e. without using a setter. In this case, the array is not retained, and released as soon as your app enters the run loop. So, if you are not using ARC, use `pedidoNomeArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] retain];` instead. But you should really use ARC since it avoids most of the common memory management problems.

**EDIT** (due to you comment):
Now it seems to me that what you need is a data model according to the [MVC software architecture pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). Your data are stored in an independent object, and both of your view controllers have a reference to this object. Your data model, which contains your "global array" could be instantiated e.g. in your application delegate or your root view controller, this is debatable, examples and discussion see [here](http://www.hollance.com/2012/02/dont-abuse-the-app-delegate/). I hope this helps.

Comment: What I need is: a global NSMutableArray where I can load when application open and then I can use the values in my ViewController.

The NSMutableArray is working ok but when I click on the button and go to another View Controller, this new view use the same class (ViewController) and in this view have the code in the "viewDidLoad" to create the array so I have a new array and no the old array that I want tiwht the old values.